# Communicating variable in vue.js between components

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I am building app using laravel and vue. I have navbar, currently it looks like:

```
<template>
<nav class="navbar">
    <p>{{msg}}</p>
</nav>
</template>
```

And I use it like here:

```
 <body class="">
        <div id="app">
            <div class="">
            <navbar></navbar>
            @yield('content')
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
```

In yield I am loading another components, so I have navbar and another component together. Now I want to override that {{msg}} variable from navbar in another components. In every component that variable will be diferent.

I do not know how to override it in components and from {{msg}} do some text. Can you help me? (That code above is all what I have)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use `msg` in other components, then you need to use `prop`

Use like:

```
props: ['msg'],
```

Then, you need to bind it like:

```
<component-name :msg="msg"></component-name>
```

In your component, you can take it like:

```
<template>{{ msg }}</template>
```

Hope you understand!

Comment: Not this way.

I have navbar and index for example. In navbar i have <p>{{msg}}</p>. Now when we are on index page that msg should turn into text for example 'index page'.  I do not know how to do it. I do not want to add another html elements. Should be that what I have.

Comment: This is the trick of `props` what is right! I don't think it may turn into different text that you want!

Comment: Can u explain me more about the code you wrote? I don't understand where put it

Comment: Ok, use `props` in file from you export it, in same file `<component-name :msg="msg"></component-name>` and get {{ msg }} in any component you want! Please refer this: https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Props

Comment: errors in navbar -  1. props must be strings when using array syntax. 2. Property or method "msg" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option

Comment: Should I add another component for that <p></p>?

Comment: Can you please refer the link which i provided for once? I think you get more idea!

Comment: I did it :/
I do not know what u exactly mean, but i have two components - navbar and index. In navbar I have that msg variable in place where it should be. Now when we are on the page called index I want to display some text in that msg place. You know, navbar is above page so I want to have that text in navbar.

Comment: I can't bind it just like <p :msg="msg"></p>?

Comment: In navbar do this: `props: ['msg'],` and `<index-component-name :msg="msg"></index-component-name>` and you can use in index page like `<p>{{ msg }}</p>` I think you might understand! :) This is the use of `prop`

Comment: Not this way my friend :) 
You don;'t understand :)

Comment: I must have that <p> text in navbar and I want to have that p text different on every page

Comment: Can you try this please?: `v-bind:msg="msg"`

Comment: Okay, i did it - <p v-bind:msg="msg"></p> and in props ['msg'] and I get  props must be strings when using array syntax.

Comment: Is this error '`props must be strings when using array syntax.`' ??:

Comment: Okay I repaired it. So I have props and that bind in navbar. What next in index component?

Comment: Just use `{{ msg }}` in index, i think it works! Just try first, Not perfect sure :)

Comment: Or you can use `v-model` in your index file

Comment: No, that's not work. And that's not what I want I think.
That {{msg}} must be in navbar, when you are in index page it tells you index, when you are on about page it tells about.
I think it should be like we have {{msg}} in navbar and we override it in every component like we want

Comment: Sorry, i max tried to fix your problem, anyway i gave idea about vue's `prop` :)

Comment: Please upvote if you get `prop` idea! Because i am right i think in `prop`!

Comment: Can you please accept and upvote this answer and close this issue as you only need to use to fix this and that is `prop`

Comment: No I can't, that's not helping me

Comment: Why, i am maximum try to fix your problem and spent time to your problem! The only solution is to use prop and here i describe you!

Answer (score 0):

Components can be communicate with props. You can transfer the data to another components and you can use if statement.

https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Props

Comment: Should I do it in app.js?

Comment: No need that. You have to creat props on where ever you may want to use. And after you can take the data in a html tag like that :data="dataname" https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PPmg7ntQjzc

Comment: But I don't want to add another html in my child components. Is there any way to override that variable in data() or something like this?

Comment: You are not adding any html tag. This is a component, <yield></yield> and after the props, it's happening like this <yield :props="props"></yield> like that. Yield component can be read what in side navbar, and you can act from this.