# Change laravel variable on every page using vue.js

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js

I have navbar like this:

```
<nav class="navbar">
        <p style="text-align: center; color: white;">{{ @$test}}</p>
</nav>
```

And my page looks like:

```
<body class="">
    <div id="app">
        <div class="">
        @include('navbar')
        @yield('content') <- here another components
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

How to change that @$test laravel variable using vue.js?

Comment: You probably need to define a navbar component with a prop you can use

Comment: @apokryfos tried it :), doesn't work https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46075392/communicating-variable-in-vue-js-between-components/46076011?noredirect=1#comment79115815_46076011

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using? What are you wanting to replace `@$test` with?

Answer (score 1):

Props are the only sensible thing you can do. You must make them work otherwise using vue with components will just be a pointless exercise.

Based on this response : https://stackoverflow.com/a/46076011/487813

Use a `prop` in you component:

```
props: ['test'],

<template>
<nav class="navbar">
    <p style="text-align: center; color: white;">{{test}}</p>
</nav>
</template>
```

Here `{{test}}` is the Vue.js directive to write the property value of test

In *navbar.blade.php*

```
<component-name :test="{{$test}}"></component-name>
```

Here `{{$test}}` is the blade directive to echo the PHP variable test.

```
<body class="">
    <div id="app">
        <div class="">
        @php
           $test = 'set the right value for test here or anywhere before including the navbar';
        @endphp
        @include('navbar')
        @yield('content') <- here another components
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: So, i think i am right in my answer right sir? This is my answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/46076011/487813

Comment: @HirenGohel yes, the thing added here is the passing of the PHP variable as the component prop.

Comment: Ok, thank you sir for your kind reply! @Rowinkski: please accept my answer so that other user may not waste their time! And close that issue